# zorder of a jquery ui menu

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I use jquery ui to show a menu. On this webpage, there are some images and the menu is showed behind that images.

I already tried :

```
.ui-menu { z-index: 9999999; }
```

or

```
#menu { z-index: 9999999; }
```

but it doesn't work

When I use the developer extension of chrome, I add a z-index style on the image and it didn't work either ?

You can see the problem on http://jsfiddle.net/fLHuR/1/ when you go on the menu on salzburg then test

Does someone know how to modify that behaviour ? (Note : I don't have the time to change the whole website)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comment the `z-index:3` for `#contenu` **OR** Make it as `z-index:0`

```
#contenu {
    position:absolute;
    left:280px;
    top:105px;
    width:519px;
    height:2012px;
    /*z-index:3;*/
}
```

and Add

```
#menu { z-index: 9999999; }
```

Refer to the **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/fLHuR/3/)**